# Can Adobe AIR retrieve the hardware specifications of the device it is running on?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4.5

I am writing an application which is supposed to work on various mobile devices, and i need to retrieve the device hardware on which it is running.

- Is it possible, and how ( if it is ) to retrieve the device hardware parameters ?

Comment: What specifically are you looking for? You can retrieve the OS, total ram in the system and some other things but not much. Please specify.

Comment: i need the CPU, amount of RAM, VGA chip, bluetooth chip, gps chip, gsm chip.

Comment: Look at the Capabilities class for some information.  Some feature checks, such as Geolocation, have moved into a specific class using the isSupported property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Flextras pointed out, check out the documentation for the following classes:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/sensors/Geolocation.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/System.html

You may find additional stuff of interest within the flash.system.* package:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/package-detail.html